# Should I quit my average interesting long-term contract for a 12 months interesting postdoc in photovoltaics experimental physics ?

Tags: phd, research-process, postdocs

[I am French, so my english is not perfect ...]

2 years later I graduated from my Ph.D. in experimental nuclear physics. That was a nice time however tough sometimes.
Then I was unemployed for about 16 months as I could not find a postdoc in the field. Maybe I "missed" something, but some friend of mine had the same trouble too. 
After those 16 months I was finally contacted by a company to perform maintenance on a nuclear computation code (fixing bugs, solving users troubles ...). I have been doing it for a year now, and I must say it is not very interesting. Seems that I was bad luck as every two year the code has to go through complex changes which implies boring things to do for the person doing my job (producing reports and so on). But I think the problem is more profund than that, I am just not found of doing bug fixing, answering people who kept telling me than things do not work, and of course, I won't do physics in this job (according to my predecessors who stayed 4 years) even if is related to it.

I don't feel like I will earn the Nobel Prize one day, as I know I am not a genius, but I am very interested in physics and I feel quite depressed not doing it anymore for a living.

Now, I have an opportunity for a postdoctorate in spectoscopy on solar materials. It seems complex but also very interesting. The salary will be a bit less than what I earn today.

I don't have a family right now (not even a gf) and have a bit of money left.

Do you think I shoud jump on this postdoc ? Seems so cool but I am afraid having troubles to find a job afterwards, even if the solar energy field (and more generaly surface spectroscopic experiment) is more trendy than the nuclear one.

All opinions are welcome, thanks a lot !

Comment: From what I could understand, I believe it will fall into the category "only you can answer that". It is your life, your decisions. Also, the question itself is too broad. If there is any specific question, considering the site rules, that would be better too.

Comment: I don't think anyone can make this decision for you, and SE sites are not really the place to gather opinions - see the [help/dont-ask]. Is there anything you don't *know* that we can help you with instead, that could help you make the decision?